# Retrofit 2/OkHttp: Cancel all running requests

Tags: java, android, retrofit, okhttp

I'm using Retrofit 2-beta2 with OkHttp 2.7.0.

To get the `OkHttpClient` object from Retrofit I'm using the [Retrofit .client()](https://square.github.io/retrofit/2.x/retrofit/retrofit/Retrofit.html#client--) method and to cancel all it's running requests, I'm calling it's [cancel(Object tag)](http://square.github.io/okhttp/2.x/okhttp/com/squareup/okhttp/OkHttpClient.html#cancel-java.lang.Object-) method but the requests still keep running and I get a response.

Even the client's `Dispatcher`'s [getQueuedCallCount()](http://square.github.io/okhttp/2.x/okhttp/com/squareup/okhttp/Dispatcher.html#getQueuedCallCount--) and [getRunningCallCount()](http://square.github.io/okhttp/2.x/okhttp/com/squareup/okhttp/Dispatcher.html#getRunningCallCount--) return 0 after calling cancel().

Is there anything else that I need to do for this to work? Or could it be a bug in OkHttp?

As a workaround, I'm calling `shutdownNow()` on the client's `ExecutorService`  but I'd prefer a cleaner solution.

Comment: After going through the source code I now understand why this doesn't work. I'm setting the tag on the `Request` using an interceptor therefore creating a new `Request` object. `OkHttpClient.cancel(Object tag)` does nothing since the original `Request` (on which `cancel()` is called since it's present in the `Dispatcher`'s request queue) still doesn't have a tag set . It seems Retrofit doesn't expose any method or interface to set a tag on the original `Request` object.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

**UPDATE:** This is now much easier to achieve in OkHttp 3 by using `Dispatcher` which has a `cancelAll()` method. The dispatcher is returned from `OkHttpClient.dispatcher()`.

**Old Solution:**
The only way to do this (that I could find) is to create a subclass of `OkHttpClient` and use that with Retrofit.

```
class OkHttpClientExt extends OkHttpClient {
    static final Object TAG_CALL = new Object();

    @Override
    public Call newCall(Request request) {
        Request.Builder requestBuilder = request.newBuilder();
        requestBuilder.tag(TAG_CALL);
        return super.newCall(requestBuilder.build());
    }
}
```

The following line cancels all requests with tag `TAG_CALL`. Since the class above sets `TAG_CALL` on all requests, so all requests are cancelled.

```
retrofit.client().cancel(OkHttpClientExt.TAG_CALL);
```

Comment: Rather than extending the OkHttpClient you can just add a RequestInterceptor and add your tag for each request.

Comment: @Matthew Yes, setting the tag with an `Interceptor` would have worked as well. However, with OkHttp 3, this is no longer required since `Dispatcher` provides `cancelAll()` method which cancels all requests irrespective of tags.

Comment: Wasn't aware of the `Dispatcher` class, very helpful!

Comment: I can't access dispatcher() method and cancelAll() method from either OkHttpClient.Builder or Retrofit instance. Please provide me a complete example.

Comment: @Madhan You can access `dispatcher()` from the `OkHttpClient` instance that's returned by `OkHttpClient.Builder.build()`.

http://square.github.io/okhttp/3.x/okhttp/okhttp3/OkHttpClient.html#dispatcher--

http://square.github.io/okhttp/3.x/okhttp/okhttp3/OkHttpClient.Builder.html#build--