# Cancel all request by retrofit2

Tags: android, retrofit2

I make an application use youtube API. The first I use `Retrofit` to load list video then I continue use `Retrofit` to load all information of Video in the list.

Because the `listview` support refresh and loadmore I need `cancel` all request to recall.

I know **Call** have `cancel()` function to cancel request. I can cancel all request by put all **Call** to a Stack and call `cancel()` for each **Call**.

Are there more better solution ?

Comment: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34367910/retrofit-2-okhttp-cancel-all-running-requests](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34367910/retrofit-2-okhttp-cancel-all-running-requests)

Comment: I read this thread. But I don't know `retrofit.client().cancel(...) `, the function not found.

Comment: in that thread already said use `dispatcher` for this becoz i have check `dispatcher` has `cancelAll();` method

Answer (score 5):

Suppose i have

```
 HttpLoggingInterceptor interceptor = new HttpLoggingInterceptor().setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY);

 OkHttpClient.Builder httpClient = new OkHttpClient.Builder();

 OkHttpClient client = httpClient.addInterceptor(interceptor).build();

 Retrofit.Builder builder =
        new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl("MY URL")
                .client(new OkHttpClient.Builder().addInterceptor(interceptor).build())
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create());

 OkHttpClient.Builder httpClient = new OkHttpClient.Builder();
```

Now create service with `Dispatcher` and set to `Retrofit`

```
 Dispatcher dispatcher=new Dispatcher();
 dispatcher.setMaxRequests(totalRequest);
 httpClient.dispatcher(dispatcher);

 Retrofit retrofit = builder.client(client).build();
 Service servicee = retrofit.create(serviceClass)
```

and just call from any where

```
dispatcher.cancelAll();
```

Comment: How does dispatcher cancel the request which are already posted and there will be callback executes. As i have used dispatcher onStop() to cancel request but the running request. But on the slow network . The request which are posted are still called the callback and lead to some exception.